# Book series featuring a boy who gains powers and gets nabbed by the multiverse police as a result

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this series in the 8th grade, 2014.

A boy is doing his daily thing when he feels powers growing, and he gets nabbed by multiverse police of sorts because of this.

The boy who was nabbed finds a group of multiverse police people (the people who nabbed him in the first place?) to teach him how to hunt and fight this alternate version of himself and I vaguely remember not all members being human specifically.

The reason he is gaining powers is because an alternate self is killing off his 11 alternates so he can have greater life force and powers. Each time he finds and kills an alternate self, the remaining alternates gain the powers as well.

There are 12 known dimensions and an alleged 13th dimension that isn’t known as fact or fiction, but the murderous alternate self resides there.

Any ideas? It’s been bothering me for a long time, I just want to find the series

Comment: It sounds a bit like the 2001 film, *The One*, but obviously that did not involve a teenager.

Comment: Honourable mention to James Wong's [The One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_(2001_film)) starring Jet Li.

Comment: Everything I search leads me there and it is exactly like that but no cop and it’s a book series instead @FuzzyBoots

Comment: Welcome to SF&F!  Can you pin down when you read this?  You only say "a long time," but an approximate year would be helpful.  You also say it's a series; can you identify which plot elements would span books, or the climactic conflict of one of them?